# directory and sub directory pass as a string argument

Tags: python, file, recursion, directory

**Problem is** Recursively calling the directory and sub directory and pass it as a string.

In line `input_file_list = sys.argv[1:]` I can pass the argument as a single directory but what I want to pass all the directory and sub directory

```
def main():
    total_lines= comment_lines= blank_lines= code_lines=0
    input_file_list = []


    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        try:
            inputs_file = open("input.txt", "r")
            for line in inputs_file.readlines():
                if line[-1] == "\n":
                    input_file_list.append(line[:-1])
                else:
                    input_file_list.append(line)
            inputs_file.close()
            if len(input_file_list) == 0:
                print usage
                sys.exit(1)
        except IOError:
            print usage
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        #Recursively counting the file numbers
        input_file_list = sys.argv[1:]
#        #Recursively counting the file numbers
#        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
#           for name in files:
#               input_file_name = os.path.join(root, name)
#               #print input_file_name



     #TODO: -Recursively read all the files
    for input_file_name in input_file_list:
        try:
            current_file = open(input_file_name, "r")
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: os.walk() is not ok ?

Comment: Don't you have the solution to your problem in the commented piece of code?

Comment: @fred.yu os.walk works listed all the directories and subdirectories. The issue is in commented line passing the value of input_file_list. I need to pass this input_file_list in the next for loop.

Comment: @HansThen I am still working on this commented To do list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
def get_all_files(parent):
    paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent):
        for name in files:
            paths.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return paths
```